# How to hide the navigation bar when presenting a View Controller from a View in SwiftUI iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uikit

I have a view which navigates to a View Controller (View Controller is wrapped in UIViewControllerRepresentable).

The view controller has a navigation bar of its own. But when I navigate to the screen, the navigation bar gets placed below the back button.

How can I display the navigation bar of the view controller and the back button in the same bar?

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView(content: {
            NavigationLink {
                SimpleViewRepresentable()
            } label: {
                Text("Present View Controller")
            }
        })
    }
}

class SimpleViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 44))
        view.addSubview(navBar)
        navBar.backgroundColor = .red
        self.navigationItem.title = "Title"
    }
}

struct SimpleViewRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
        let vc =  UINavigationController(rootViewController: SimpleViewController())
        vc.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
        return vc
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController, context: Context) {}
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to fix some codes like this:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView(content: {
        NavigationLink {
            SimpleViewRepresentable().navigationBarHidden(true)
        } label: {
            Text("Present View Controller")
        }
    })
}
```

Please check and let me know if it doesn't work at your side.